# Why can't I access my HDR toning?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have three layers open in Photoshop.

Two are images. One is a text layer.

I flattened and merged the background image which I originally filled with black and applied a gradient to.

I then tried to apply HDR toning but the HDR toning option is greyed out although the Shadow/Highlighting is not.

Why can't I access my HDR toning?

I tried converting it to a smart object and ensuring it's rasterised; still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using CMYK color mode. With this mode HDR Toning  is not working. You need to change color mode to **RGB** or **Grayscale** mode.

Comment: Thank you. I was just about to come back and answer my question but you are correct. By switching back after using HDR in RGB, should I expect that I will lose the HDR effect or that the effect will change drastically when changing back to CMYK?

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen You are welcome. I think no.